# How to varify that 2 particular values exist on the same row in a separate workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example:  I have a number in cell `E2` in workbook1.  I have another number in `A13` in workbook1.  I have a 3rd cell that needs to highlight green in workbook1 under the condition that values in `E2` and `A13` reside on the same row within workbook2.

Below is a my current formula that partially gives me what I need but can't figure out how to only validate the condition if the values reside on the same row in workbook2.

`=INDEX('[Print Tracking.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B,AND(MATCH(A13,'[Print Tracking.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B,0),MATCH(E2,'[Print Tracking.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,0)))`

Have any ideas on what the solution is?

Comment: Note, consider "Print Tracking" as workbook2.

Comment: What columns can the values be in in workbook2? A and B?

Comment: Correct. E2 will be in column A and A13 would be column B of workbook2.

Comment: I think maybe I need some kind of True or False validation?

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNTIFS and check if the result is greater than 0.

```
=COUNTIFS('[Print Tracking.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,E2,'[Print Tracking.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B,A13)>0
```

Comment: BigBen, I'm hoping you can assist with one small addition to what you have supplied.  I have another cell that I want to show true or false just like what we discussed.  Except I need this one to also tell me if column D in Print Tracking shows "True".  If "True", then I want the cell in workbook1 to be "True".  Here's my uupdated formula that isn't quite working...

Comment: =COUNTIFS('[Print Tracking.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,$E$2,'[Print Tracking.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B,$A14,IF('[Print Tracking.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D:$D="TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"),)>0

Comment: I realized I'm leaving out "criteria3" but that's because I'm sure I'm not using the correct formula to achieve this.

Comment: There should not be any `IF`... inside the `COUNTIFS` - it's criteria range, then criterion: `COUNTIFS('[Print Tracking.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,E2,'[Print Tracking.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B,A13,'[Print Tracking.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D:$D,"TRUE")>0`.